# how to delete all users and posts based on 'user_meta'?

Tags: wordpress, posts

I have developed a small wordpress application where It has Institutes(wp user), Trainers(wp user), Trainees(wp user), courses(custom post) and notifications(custom post). All the application is working fine but If I delete an institute all the information belongs to that institute like Trainers, Trainee, notifications & courses should also be deleted. While I was creating the 'institute' user I am storing the all the related info like first name, last name in wordpress table 'wp_users' and 'institute name' is storing as 'user meta' with key 'inistitute_name' in 'wp_usermeta' table like below is my code:

```
  $user_data = array(
                'ID' => '',
                'user_pass' => '',
                'user_login' => $first_name,
                'user_email' => $user_email,
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name' => $last_name,
                'role' => 'admin'//get_option('default_option')
            );
            $random_password = wp_generate_password(8,false);
            $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'inistitute_name',$insititute_name );
```

While creating Trainer (or) Trainee my code is like below:

```
$user_data = array(
                   'ID' => '',
                   'user_pass' => '',
                   'user_login' => $first_name,
                   'user_email' => $trainer_email,
                   'first_name' => $first_name,
                   'last_name' => $last_name,
                   'role' => 'trainer'
             ); 
            $random_password = wp_generate_password(8,false);
            $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'inistitute_name',$this->institute_name[0] );
            wp_set_password($random_password, $user_id);
```

While creating courses my code is like below:

```
 $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
 $institute_name = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'inistitute_name', true);
 $post = array(
                'post_title'    => $title,
                'post_content'  => $description,
                'post_status'   => 'publish', 
                'post_type' => "courses"  
            );
 $id = wp_insert_post($post);
 update_post_meta( $id, 'inistitute_name', $institute_name );
```

Suppose let us say if a institute 'abcd' is deleted then all the information like 'trainer', 'trainee', 'courses' & 'notifications' associated with that institute should also be deleted based on a 'user_meta' field. Is it possible to delete? (or) did I do any mistake? can anyone tell me what was I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution form wordpress.stackexchange.com link to that question is here

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/249435/how-to-delete-all-users-and-posts-based-on-user-meta/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$user_args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'inistitute_name',
    'meta_value' => 'your_value', //<-- replace it by your user_meta value.
    'meta_compare' => '=',
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'number' => -1
);
// Custom query.
$user_query = new WP_User_Query($user_args);

// Get query results.
$users = $user_query->get_results();

//print_r($users);
// Check for users
if (!empty($users))
{
    // Loop over users.
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        // Get each user's data.
        $user_info = get_userdata($user->ID);

        $user_display_name = $user_info->display_name;

        $args = array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'any', //<-- you can Specific type by array('post', 'my_custom_post')
            'author' => $user_id
        );

        // get all posts by this user: posts, pages, attachments, etc..
        $user_posts = get_posts($args);

        if (!empty($user_posts))
        {
            // delete all the user posts
            foreach ($user_posts as $user_post)
            {
                wp_delete_post($user_post->ID, true);
            }
        }
        wp_delete_user( $user_id, $reassign );
    }
}
else
{
    //"no user found"
}
```

I haven't tested this code, out form my WP knowledge.

**Please note before testing this code do take a Database backup.**